# jQuery scripts not ready after back button

Tags: php, jquery, pjax

I try make web like github with PJAX. Page works normal if use PJAX links. Problem is if click back button. Content is loaded, but jquery scripts are not ready. Go to http://test.hopeseeker.com/, go down and click on emotion (Loved) page is loaded with PJAX. Then click back button on browser. Index is loaded, but jQuery is not ready.

Comment: This is not how [so] operates. Please add the relevant code to your post and try to minimize the code to demonstrate the exact problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

To load the jquery added in your page, you need to call it after the pjax event is completed.

To make it work also on browser's back/ forward button clicks, you can use pjax-end event.

```
$("#pjax_container_id").bind('pjax:end', function() {
  // call your jquery functions
});
```

Hope this would help you.

Thanks.